# JavaScript href:function(); Syntax in vs 2012 ASP.NET MVC template

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

The new MVC template which came with VS 2012 contains the line of JavaScript below in "_LoginPartial.cshtml". I have a question about this JavaScript syntax. Is this JavaScript or Asp.Net specific syntax? Can we use JavaScript calls in normal HTML?

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<a href="javascript:foo();">..</a>` in normal html markup - it's not Asp.Net specific - but I don't think it's regarded as very good unobtrusive js. See the discussion here: [How to call javascript function instead of href in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003867/how-to-call-javascript-function-instead-of-href-in-html) where the accepted answer from @Dutchie432 includes this better form:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="foo(args);">
```

There is also some more discussion of alternatives here: http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jlinktut.htm

Answer (score 1):

I see this is a Log off link, and the JS seems to be submitting the form. Surley you can just have an action in your controller that deals with logging off ? that would be a better design.

As mentioned before this format of JS is not unique to the .net template you are using , it can be applied to plain HTML.