# Making a clickable link in a d3 tooltip that executes javascript

Tags: d3.js

I need a link in the tooltip text for my d3 scatterplot which invokes javascript

I've read this: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c37cb8e630aaef7df30d.

And I removed `'pointer-events: none;'` from the css of my tooltip as required.

- I've tried setting the `href` in the link to both `'#'` and `'javascript:void(0)'`.
- I've tried using a jquery click handler `($('a.my-class').click(function(){...}))`.

Nothing has worked. When I click the link the javascript is not invoked. If I set the `href` to a URL and click the link, however, the browser does go to the URL I specified.

So why doesn't it work with javascript?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What do you mean when you say that it doesn't work?

Comment: do you have a JSFiddle ?

Comment: @AJ_91 Here is the actual code in github:
https://github.com/laran/eisenhower/blob/master/components/plot/scatterplot.js#L107
Here is where I enable pointer-events:
https://github.com/laran/eisenhower/blob/master/components/plot/scatterplot.css#L16

Comment: @LarsKotthoff There are no errors. It just doesn't do anything. In the code I've linked above there are no handlers for clicking on the links (matching selector a.tooltip-task-link). As I said, I've tried various methods, none of which worked.

Comment: Have you tried simply calling the Javascript function in the `href`  as e.g. in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003867/how-to-call-javascript-function-instead-of-href-in-html)?