# What the difference between returning or not?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What's the effect of adding 'return false' to an onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event)
>   [When and why to 'return false' in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855360/when-and-why-to-return-false-in-javascript)

I mean, if I have this function :

```
 function openMask() {
     alert("enter");
 }
```

is it better call it as :

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openMask()">Link</a>
```

or :

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openMask(); return false;">Link</a>
```

??? I'm really curious about it! Never understood the difference...

Comment: Please search first next time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a DOM event handler (such as `onclick`), returning `true` means "continue with the event", and returning `false` means "don't".

In this case, it's not entirely meaningful because your `href` is already `javascript:void(0)` (which won't do anything).

Note, though, that `javascript:` URIs should really be avoided, and that this isn't very helpful for non-Javascript users, so you should provide a fallback page, and then the `return false` becomes more meaningful:

JS:

```
function openMask() {
   alert("enter");
   return false; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="fallbackpage.html" onclick="return openMask();">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

The best would be to use:

```
 <a href="/page/with/opened/mask" onclick="openMask(); return false;">Link</a>
```

So users without JavaScript (including Google Bot) can use your site.

Comment: +1, absolutely should have an `href` that makes sense regardless of JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

`return false` causes the browser to ignore the `href`. In your specific example it changes nothing since the `href` does nothing, but it would matter if you had something like `href='#'`

Comment: And is better write `javascript:void(0);` or `javascript:void(0)` (with or without `;`)?

Comment: @markzzz: The best is to have a proper URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842953/or-javascriptvoid0 . What if JavaScript is disabled? Your link won't do anything.

Comment: @Felix Kling : what do you mean? I won't to link to any ways...

Comment: @markzzz: Then why do you use a link at all? That's their only purpose, to link to somewhere. If you just want to have something clickable, use a button and style it according to your needs. A button would be the semantically most correct element in this situation.

Comment: You can style a button as a link (on IE7 for example). Just check this http://jsfiddle.net/NcCVj/3/ : you will see sme margin/padding on IE7 that shouldnt be presents...

Answer (score 1):

```
return false
```

means prevent the default behavior of an event. in your example, that's prevent the browser to open the url of link