# What is the right href value for a JavaScript anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, href

I usually have to bind a JavaScript function to an anchor-click event. That is easy using jquery or the `onclick` inline attribute.

But, my problem is that I never know what the **best way to keep `href` empty is**.

For instance:

1. `<a href="javascript:void(0)">` - It seems like a bit too much code for just being empty
2. `<a href=#>` - If I don't want to move to another page, I must return
       false in the JavaScript call
3. `<a href>` - This option breaks the
       cursor and hover style and the browser doesn't render it as a link
4. `<a>` - idem

What is the best `href` value for empty anchors? I'm not interested to keep functionality without JavaScript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Href for JavaScript links: "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842953/or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: If the element does not have the function of a link, then don't use a link. Use a `button` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right one is to use an empty `a` element `href` attribute and bind the click event in Javascript.

For unobtrusive design, you should have a `href` attribute with a proper link (so those without Javascript can still use the site) and remove the attribute in Javascript, binding the click event.

If you are simply using the `a` element as a target to bind the click event to, consider using a `div` or `span` instead.

Comment: That is if click does navigation (eg. ajax). That is not always.

Comment: Using a `button` might be even more appropriate, depending on the function.

Comment: That is really dabatable, since buttons are often browser and OS dependent and hardly stylable.

Comment: @Rok: They are easy to style, just like any other element as well. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9j5yb/1/

Comment: Sure, I know. But it takes few lines to remove all the OS dependent code. At the end of the day - the difference is only semantic - for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do not use A element. You can as well make DIV clickable or any other element.

Or you can also simply leave href attribute out, like so.

```
<a onclick="myFunction();">dasd</a>
```

If you also want to look it like a link, put this in CSS:

```
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;    
}​
```

Comment: If you omit `href`, it is not rendered as a link.

Comment: What do you mean by that, that's not true. The element still obeys all the CSS rules.

Comment: That is just browser predefined rendering, which you shouldn't use if you care about design. Always style links to your linking. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/b59Pa/

Comment: What's with that fiddle? It the same I showed. Anyways, in that case it is not used as an anchor or link and it would be more appropriate to use `button` instead. Of course you can style any element in any way you want with CSS, but your original answer suggested one could just omit `href`, which is not true.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b59Pa/3/ It IS NOT. Asker said: "But, my problem is that I never knew what is the best way to keep href empty."

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally a firm believe in using JavaScript to **extend** functionality, not replace. With that said, I leave anchors pointing to a "safe" fall-back of the action I'm really just executing with javascript. Simply put:

```
<a href="/users/create" class="user-create"></a>
```

Then, supplement (and return false) if javascript was able to successfully load and bind to the element, otherwise still provide the user the ability to accomplish the task if they don't have javascript (either blocked via plugin or just not loaded).

Comment: That is if click does navigation (eg. ajax). That is not always.

Comment: @RokKralj: With the exception of UI transitions, I disagree. Any other click you can perform is perfectly acceptable to perform in a page transition (not as pretty, sure, but possible). -- Follow-up: Think of every action you can perform right here on SO: Commenting, voting, flagging, etc. All can be done with a follow-up to another page. It'd be ugly (by today's standards) but feasible (how did they do it in the 90's?) The exception would be "add comment" and alike which show/hide content, but without javascript you'd just keep it visible at all times.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
<a href="javascript:;"></a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:void;"></a>
```

is the best way to indicate empty anchor.

and

```
<a href="#someId"></a>
```

will move the page to the dom element which has id="someId"

Answer (score 0):

it all depends. if you are clicking an anchor to open a panel on the page then I am happy to use option 2 but only if I insert that anchor with javascript.

this then means with javascript disabled the anchor doesn't show and the panel should be visible.

if the link goes somewhere then you need the actual link address like brad christy and odid said.

Answer (score 0):

`<a href=#>ABC</a>`

=> on click of above link it will set url in address bar which makes flickering of document or resetting scroll position

to avoid above problem,
    `<a href=# onclick="return false" >abc</a>`
can be used and bind event handler using jQuery as usual
or you can execute any function on onclick which return false value.